# Ion slider - onFinish is fired up when page is loaded (not due user action on slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider

i have problem with ionslider. I've noticed that when page is loaded plugin calls action  onFinish without user action. On demo site: ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_interactions.html plugin reacts only when end moving indicator on slider.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $j("#priceSlider").ionRangeSlider({
                                    type: "double",
                                    min: <?php echo $row['minPrice']; ?>,
                                    max: <?php echo $row['maxPrice']; ?>,
                                    prefix: "zł",
                                    onFinish: function (data) {
                                        var path = base_url + 'Ajax_Filters/reloadFilters';
                                        var currentUrl = window.location.href;

                                        window.history.pushState("", "", currentUrl+"?price_from="+data.from+"&price_to="+data.to);
                                        $j.ajax({
                                            type: 'post', 
                                            url: path, 
                                            data: {
                                                currentUrl : currentUrl 
                                            }, success: function (data) {

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

Script description - It's designed to filter products by price in given range. Once price is changed filter send ajax request to refresh product list and other filters to match query. Once filtered it will alter url to new ones with new values  like "price_from = some price.
Due onFinish problem script rewrites url just after document.ready is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In the ion.rangeSlider.js there is a setting called:

```
this.is_first_update = true;
```

Changing this to the false value should fix your problem!

Best,
Seb

Comment: Where does this go?